# Proof of Chebyshev's inequality for a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have learnt the Chebyshev's inequality for a continuous case like log-normal and normal distributions and in trying to understand the application I came across the question:

For a geometric distribution $p(x)=2^{-x}$; $x = 1, 2, \ldots$ prove that Chebyshev's inequality gives $\operatorname P(|x-2| \le 2) > 0.5$, while the actual probability is $\dfrac{15}{16}$.

I have not learnt the discrete case but it's haunting me now. Your help on how to answer, or the answer to the question above will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality applies to any real valued random variable with a finite variance. Apply it (if you do not remember the statement, check your lecture notes or Wikipedia) to your geometric random variable -- ypu will need first to show the expectation is 2, and to compute the variance; and then compute (explicitly, from the pdf) the actual values of $\Pr [ |X-2| > 2 ] $. Then compare the two values... you should get an upper bound of 1/2 with Chebyshev, and an actual value of 1/16 by direct computation.

Comment: Would you explicitly show me how to do this?

Comment: I cannot really do that from my phone, but if no one has answered by the time I have access to a computer I will.

Comment: Thank you and will appreciate

Answer (score 1):

*From my previous comment:*

> Chebyshev's inequality applies to any real valued random variable with a finite variance. Apply it *(if you do not remember the statement, check your lecture notes or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement))* to your geometric random variable — you will need first to show the expectation is 2, and to compute the variance; and then compute (explicitly, from the pdf) the actual values of $\Pr[\lvert X−2\rvert>2]$. Then compare the two values... you should get an upper bound of $1/2$ with Chebyshev, and an actual value of $1/16$ by direct computation.

---

In detail:

> **Theorem.** (Chebyshev's inequality) Assume $X$ is a real-valued random variable such that $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var} X < \infty$. Then, for any $k>0$,
>   $$
> \Pr[\lvert X - \mathbb{E} \rvert > k\sigma ] < \frac{1}{k^2}
> $$

Let $X\sim \operatorname{Geom}(2)$.  We want bounds on $\Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert \leq 2] = 1 - \Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert > 2]$.

First, let use compute $\mathbb{E}X$ and $\operatorname{Var} X$ in view of applying Chebyshev's inequality.

- **Expectation and variance:**
  $$
  \mathbb{E} X = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \Pr[X=n] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} = 
  \frac{1}{2}f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 2
  $$
  where $f(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ is defined on $(-1,1)$ (power series), so that $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}$ and $xf'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n}$. From the expression $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, we get $xf'(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, and for $x=1/2$ this gives $2$ indeed.

Similarly, we can compute the variance
$$
\operatorname{Var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2
=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-4
$$
and the same sort of trick we give us $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$, leading to $\operatorname{Var} X=2$.

- **Applying Chebyshev:** from there, we get, by applying the inequality with $k=\sqrt{2}$ (since $\sigma = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var} X} = \sqrt{2}$),
  $$
  \Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert > 2] = \Pr[\lvert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\rvert > k\sqrt{\operatorname{Var} X}] < \frac{1}{(2/\sqrt{2})^2} = \frac{1}{2}
  $$

  This leads to
  $$
  \Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert \leq 2]  > 1- \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.
  $$

**We can also compute the probability directly:**

$$
\Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert > 2] = \Pr[X > 4] = \sum_{n=5}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^5}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{16}
$$
so that
$$
\Pr[\lvert X-2\rvert \leq 2] = 1- \frac{1}{16} = \frac{15}{16}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very @Clement C, what is your émail adress

Comment: That's not really relevant... why do you ask?